# customize admin login page WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs

I am trying to cotumize the login page of the admin but without touching

```
<admin~dir>/templates/login.tpl
```

i want to make modification in my template files so when i switch to it the login page changes.
is there a way to inject a css file or override login.tpl from

```
<admin~dir>/templates/my-template
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can create a new admin theme to add to the selections available to admin area users it does not seem like you are able to modify the admin login page without actually modifying the default template file.

For admin theme info see: https://docs.whmcs.com/Admin_Area_Template_Files

If you really need to update the theme for the login page my suggestion would be to make a backup copy of the original login.tpl file (call it login.tpl.orig or something) and make all the changes you want on your login.tpl file. Or better yet track your changes in some sort of version control system so you can easily merge changes that WHMCS makes down the road when they do updates.

Comment: yes it's a good idea , but i still need to do the same job with each update